# How to locate HTML elements in SpreadJS

Tags: html5-canvas, spreadjs

My company uses SpreadJS to embed an Excel like sheet into a web page.  I'm trying to find a way to create automation tests for this, but I'm unable to locate any of the document information due to the following error:
"You need a browser which full supports HTML5 Canvas to run SpreadJS".   I've tried several different browsers, all of which are up to date, and yet I still run into the same issue.

Does anyone know a way around this?
[image]

Here is an online example.  Let say I just want to modify cell A1 and then retrieve its value:

driver = webdriver.Chrome(paht_to_driver_variable) driver.get("grapecity.com/spreadjs/designer/index.html")

Comment: Seeing that message on dev tools doesn't mean that the canvas isn't rendered. It's showing the fallback content. Your question is lacking the code you are using. Are you trying to read pixels off the canvas? I am voting to close until you specify exactly the code that is trying to access the content. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to learn how to ask a question that is easier to answer and helpful to the entire community.

Comment: @JuanMendes there is really no code to show.  I'm trying to find out how to update elements on SpreadJs and there doesn't appear to be any documentation for it.  If you would like to see some code, here is as far as i've gotten so far:

driver = webdriver.Chrome(paht_to_driver_variable)
driver.get("https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/designer/index.html")

Once i'm on this page there are no elements for me to grab.  No ids, classes, etc.